# search items in a text file in c programming

Tags: c

```
char SearchItemInformation()
{
    intSIZE = 50;
    FILE *inFile;
    int i = 0;
    char ans, enter, string[50];
    struct Item item[SIZE];
    inFile = fopen("stock.txt", "r");
    printf("Please enter the item number that you would like to search:\n");

    scanf("%d%c", &i, &enter);

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        fscanf(inFile, "%d\n%s\n%d\n%s\n%d\n%.1f kg\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",
               &item[i].itemnum, item[i].itemname, &item[i].itemnum,
               item[i].category, &item[i].quantity, &item[i].weight,
               item[i].recipient, item[i].destination, item[i].status);
    }
    printf("%d\n%s\n%d\n%s\n%d\n%.1f kg\n%s\n%s\n%s\n\n",
           item[i].itemnum, item[i].itemname, item[i].itemnum,
           item[i].category, item[i].quantity, item[i].weight,
           item[i].recipient, item[i].destination, item[i].status);
    do
    {
        printf("Do you want to search for another item(y/n):");
        scanf("%c%c", &ans, &enter);
        if ((ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n'))
            printf("invalid input");
    } while ((ans != 'y') && (ans != 'n'));
    fclose(inFile);
    return(ans);
}
```

Although it could show the first line correctly, the rest of the item couldn't be shown correctly. I would love to know why and how can I improve it. 
this is one of the items that I would like to search for:

```
1003
orange laptop computer dx5
235524
electronics
1
1.8 kg
chan tai man
mong kok
delivery
```

Comment: *the rest of the item couldn't be shown correctly* - what is actual output?

Comment: You should test that the `fscanf()` succeeded — that it read 9 items successfully.  Your `do { … } while` loop at the end is funny because regardless of whether the user types 'y' or 'n', the processing stops.  You need to move the input loop above the prompt and entry of the item number.  You probably need a loop around the 'prompt and search and again' code.

Comment: @Pavel The actual output should be  like this:
{
1003
orange laptop computer dx5
235524
electronics
1
1.8 kg
chan tai man
mong kok
delivery
}
however, it now only shows one line of correct information which is the first line while the others just random numbers.